# Invalid attempt to read when reader is closed. VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting an **Invalid attempt to read when reader is closed** error after clicking the Save Button. I believe that the error comes from the first Dr.Read(), so I tried removing all **Dr.Close()** within this code but I still got the same error.

```
    Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    Try
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save this product?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Dim bid As String = ""
            Dim cid As String = ""
            SqlConn.Open()
            SqlCmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT ID from tblbrand WHERE Brand LIKE '" & cboBrand.Text & "'", SqlConn)
            SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dr.Read()
            If Dr.HasRows Then
                bid = Dr(0).ToString()
            End If
            Dr.Close()
            SqlConn.Close()

            SqlConn.Open()
            SqlCmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT ID from tblcategory WHERE Category LIKE '" & cboCategory.Text & "'", SqlConn)
            SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dr.Read()
            If Dr.HasRows Then
                cid = Dr(0).ToString()
            End If
            Dr.Close()
            SqlConn.Close()

            SqlConn.Open()
            SqlCmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblproduct (PCode, Pdesc, BID, CID, Price) VALUES (@PCode, @Pdesc, @BID, @CID, @Price)", SqlConn)
            SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCode", PCodeBox.Text)
            SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pdesc", PDescBox.Text)
            SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BID", bid)
            SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", cid)
            SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", PriceBox.Text)
            SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            SqlConn.Close()
            ProductListForm.LoadProduct()
            MessageBox.Show("Product has been successfully saved.", "System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Clear()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        SqlConn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

and I have these two Subs to populate combobox. They execute after clicking a button in another form.

```
Public Sub Loadbrand()
    cboBrand.Items.Clear()
    SqlConn.Open()
    SqlCmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT Brand FROM tblbrand", SqlConn)
    Dr = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
    While Dr.Read()
        cboBrand.Items.Add(Dr(0).ToString())
    End While
    Dr.Close()
    SqlConn.Close()
End Sub
Public Sub Loadcategory()
    cboCategory.Items.Clear()
    SqlConn.Open()
    SqlCmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT Category FROM tblcategory", SqlConn)
    Dr = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
    While Dr.Read()
        cboCategory.Items.Add(Dr(0).ToString())
    End While
    Dr.Close()
    SqlConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: In your `Save` method, you have several references to `Dr.Read` but it is not being set or opened nearby. The other places you set `Dr` it is being closed.

Comment: I think you should restructure your code to only Save in the Save method, and Read in the Load methods

Answer (score 0):

I add `Dr = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()` before `Dr.Read()` and I removed the `SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`